# How to make the navigation bar appear in same line on mobile?

Tags: html, mobile, menu, blogger

In mobile view the navigation is all stacked up rather than in a line like the desktop template.

I would like the menu to be horizontal, the same way the desktop menu is, so it isn't taking up so much space.

```html
/*************************************************
*   Mobile Portrait                              *
*************************************************/

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.subscribe-box .block, .container {
    width: 300px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    .subscribe-box .block,.container {
        width:320px;
    }

.background-slider {
    height: 320px !important;
}
    #top-search{display:none}
#top-social {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999999999999;
    right: 0;
}
    
    
    #navigation-wrapper {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .slicknav_menu {
        display:block;
    }
    
    #logo img {
        max-width:320px;
        height:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You asking for Menu in horizontal style.

If you are asking for horizontal menus style then you should search for Fletro menu in Google you will get a lot tutorial for that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).